# o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor : The host [0000::0000:0000:0000:0000] is not valid

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I'm using spring boot project. Here is the situation.

When I run my spring boot project this happends. (The host address given is just a example. The real value is my laptop's IPv6 local address.)

```
2023-05-24 15:30:25.657  INFO 22252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : The host [0000::0000:0000:0000:0000] is not valid
 Note: further occurrences of request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.validatePort(HttpParser.java:984) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.readHostDomainName(HttpParser.java:969) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:45) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(AbstractProcessor.java:296) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareRequest(Http11Processor.java:784) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar:9.0.75]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I thought something was wrong with my project so I created new spring project with only spring web.

But same thing happens. It happens even I do nothing(request like localhost:8080) after running my project.

Do anyone knows what is the problem?

Actually I solved it by adding server.address=localhost at application.properties.

But at past I didn't added this and no problem occurred.

I want to know the exact cause of this problem.